# PDO в PHP, выборка данных

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Добрый день.

Имеется следующая таблица с данными `tbldata` в ней находятся 5 полей:
`id`, `hotel_name`, `city_code`, `city_name`, `url`.
Есть следующий код:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbldata");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
var_dump($result);
```

Но ничего не выводится, пустой результат. Что не так, работает через день (образно) бывает работает, бывает нет.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

В самую первую очередь надо включить в PDO режим порождения исключений, для чего при коннекте указать соответствующий параметр:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

А во-вторых, **убедиться, что ошибки РНР видны разработчику.** если в РНР происходит ошибка, то он **всегда, обязательно сообщит о ней.** Задача пользователя РНР - всегда видеть **все сообщения ою ошибках**, которые происходят в его скриптах. Таким образом он будет проинформирован о причинах той или иной проблемы, без необходимости обращаться на посторонние сайты.

Ну и убедиться в том, что в БД имеются данные, отвечающие запросу.

При выборке больших обьемов данных следует избегать использования ф-ции fetchall, а следует перебирать строки по одной в цикле через fetch.

На страницах, показываемых пользователям сайта, следует избегать выборок больших обьемов данных в принципе.

Comment: Включил режим исключений, запустил по новой все так же пусто, данные есть в таблице, тот же самый запрос в `phpmyadmin` выдает результаты.

Comment: Нашел ошибку слишком много данных попадает в выборку, поэтому результат не отображался, поставил `LIMIT 100` данные отобразились, есть ли какой нибудь способ обойти это ограничение в таблице `over 600 000` записей.

Comment: @ElSalvadore Уверен, что есть ограничение. Да и вывод всех  600К записей, это антипаттерн. Используйте сдвиг: `LIMIT 5,10 ` - выведет c 6 по 15 запись.

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, зачем делать `$pdo->prepare`, если запрос не содержит параметров. Во-вторых, при `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)` нужно указывать имя класса, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Необязательно, в других скриптах работает, только в этом не работает , наверное потому что данных много, пытался сделать через цикл `while` и `PDO::fetch()`, но он только одну запись обрабатывает, и завершается.

Comment: Ну да, функцию `fetchAll` не стоит применять тогда, когда запрос возвращает много данных. А вот про `while` и `PDO::fetch()`, что не получается? Пример кода не привел.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Vasil, сделал так: `$query = "SELECT * FROM tbldata";`   `foreach ($pdo->query($query, PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $key) {`  на локалке работает, а вот теперь проблемы с сервером, локалка у меня ubuntu, а сервак на windows server и там стоит WAMP постоянные предупреждения вылетают что нету библиотек, хотя они все есть и подключены, может из-за этого.

Comment: Конкретно что не работает на WAMP? Если проблема в модуле `PDO` , то рекомендую почитать инструкцию по установке и настройке данного модуля в Windows [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.installation.php).

Comment: `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library C:\Server\PHP\ext\php_interbase.dll (php_oci8_12.dll, php_pdo_firebird.dll, php_pdo_oci.dll, php_pspell.dll, php_sysbase_ct.dll) not be found. in Unknown on line 0`    Версия `PHP 5.6`